# How to make tabular layout in pdf?

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using fpdf to generate pdf in php.

I want following layout :[image]

Red area denotes logo while the black area denotes text.

I have used header function to generate header that is logo and the text. What I am curious to know is that how can I make tabular layout like this, i.e border for header, overall border and in the bottom text with border?

I am only able to make acknowledgment text with border.

Comment: does you header change dynamically? I mean do you need to create header and tabular layout in php or it could be pre-generated?

Answer (score 0):

`Cell` and `MultiCell` do not have an option for borders, you should just draw a rectangle around it with `Rect()`.